# UIGraphicsBeginImageContext question in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need the  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size); changed to where the .frame part pulls from webView

```
- (void) save {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size); 
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
```

WEBVIEW CODE:

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)ntype {
    NSLog(@"Scheme: %@", request.URL.scheme);

    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"save"]) {
        [self save];
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you are asking.  But I think you want to render a webview into this image.

So assuming the web view is assigned to an instance variable like `webView`, then you can simply replace `self.view` with `webView`.

```
- (void) save {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webView.frame.size); 
    [webView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
    NSLog(@"TEST");
}
```

Comment: Wait no, I didnt; I need help declaring it in the .h file

Comment: in the .h: `IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;` then link that to the the `webView` outlet in interface builder, or create it in code.  Then `webView` will be an instance variable representing your `UIWebView`.  If all this is confusing, you may want to take a few steps back and learn more fundamentals before tackling anything too complex.

Comment: Is there a way for it to be not in IBOutlet. Its all code. No IB

Comment: `webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame]`.  Just be sure to pair it with a `[webView release]` in your controller's `dealloc` method.

Comment: IBOutlet is just used as a hint it IB.  It has no real impact on the code.  See the define for it.